# VirtualBox: Cannot connect to Linux guest from OSX host

Tags: linux, macos, virtualbox

I'm trying to ssh into my linux guest from my osx host. There seems to be some trouble with the networking, I can ping the guest, but cannot ssh to it. I am using a host-only connection

on the guest:

```
adminisorsimac3:~ bill$ ifconfig vboxnet0
vboxnet0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 0a:00:27:00:00:00 
    inet 192.168.56.101 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.56.255

adminisorsimac3:~ bill$ ping 192.168.56.101
PING 192.168.56.101 (192.168.56.101): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.56.101: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.059 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.56.101: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.050 ms

adminisorsimac3:~ bill$ ssh tim@192.168.56.101
ssh: connect to host 192.168.56.101 port 22: Connection refused
```

on the host:

```
p7p1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
inet 192.168.56.101  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.56.255
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why is on the ssh command: **Connection refused**.

Is the SSH server running on your system? Execute `ps aux | grep sshd` on the Linux terminal as root, and see if SSH's daemon is even running.

If it is, check that it's using port 22. Check your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file, looking for the `Port` entry (usually near the very top). In the same file, check the `Listening Address` variable, to either be blank, or at least include the IP address of your host.